# Invoking an actionListener programmatically

Tags: java, jsp, download, actionlistener, oracle-adf

I have a use-case where in I want to invoke a fileDownloadActionListener tied to a commandButton programmatically. I DO NOT want to invoke it at the jspx level. Basically I want to conditionally invoke the fileDownloadActionListener. If a method returns true then I invoke it else I don't. If I have the fileDownloadActionListener at the jspx level, the moment the commandButton invoking this is clicked, it would fire the pop-up immediately but I want to perform a validation before firing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not as simple as it looks. The `fileDownloadActionListener` is a client behavior tag, so you can't just queue an action on the button. You must call a JavaScript method which does this for you.

I blogged this solution [here.](https://tompeez.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/validate-data-before-export-via-afexportcollectionactionlistener-or-affiledownloadactionlistener/)